# mongoDB updating values to sum and record when record already exists in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I'm struggling wrapping my head around how to do this, but hopefully I can get some help here.

I have a collection in MongoDB that has values aggregated over a day. I have an index in the collection that enforces each record to be unique (name, date).

Because of issues I don't control, there is occasionally data that is split in two when it should be one.

What I want to do is when an insert is attempted but fails because the unique condition would fail, I want to update the record with an aggregated value.

This is what I have so far...

```
update = db.collection.aggregate(
        [
            {
                "$addFields": {
                    "views": {"$sum": ["$views", "$views"]},
                    "avg_time": {"$avg": ["$avg_time", "$avg_time"]}
                }
            },
            {
                "$out": {"db": "collection"}
            }
        ]
    )
```

I think where i'm confused is, I don't see how mongoDB knows which record I'm attempting to update and how I refer to the old value in the query just can't be correct.

Comment: That aggregation pipeline will update _every_document, and then overwrite the collection with the new documents.  You maybe meant to use `$match` and `$merge`, or maybe `update`?

Comment: @Joe Thanks for that, this could've turned into a tragedy.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the `$out` Pipeline with the `$merge` Pipeline with `whenMatched` option set based on your requirement.

```js
update = db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "views": {
        "$sum": [
          "$views",
          "$views"
        ]
      },
      "avg_time": {
        "$avg": [
          "$avg_time",
          "$avg_time"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      into: "collectionName",  // Collection name you want to merge with
      on: "_id",  // The unique indexed key name which is creating the conflict
      whenMatched: "keepExisting",  // Action to perform when the reference key already exists
      whenNotMatched: "insert"  // Action to perform when there are no conflicts
    }
  }
])
```

Refer to the [MongoDB $merge pipeline documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) for more info on various match options available

Comment: Could I merge on something other than _id? Could I specify merging on the unique index constraint?

Comment: of course, you can. As long as the key is unique indexed, you won't face any problems. Although it's not necessary.